# Why does my website have no CSS styling in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, styling

My website ([http://www.cryptum.net](http://www.cryptum.net/)) seems to be missing all CSS styling in Internet Explorer 8. My drop down menu isn't showing. Everything I have styled isn't showing. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Please include code so that this question is useful after you change something on your site.

Comment: Rendering in IE 8 is not your only problem. Your site doesn't look like it's displaying properly in Chrome, either. I suspect the issues with your site's markup run deeper than bugs that you can blame on IE.

Comment: My site is displaying exactly how I want it to in Chrome and Safari

Comment: Your first problem is communication. You made some changes that were proposed, and you do not give any feedback. And to say thank you to anybody who helped you is not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
 <link ...>
```

elements into

```
 <head>
```

of the page.

You can also check W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.cryptum.net&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

There are really many errors in your document.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because your HTML markup is totally messed up. Choose a doctype and make sure your markup validates for it. I'd suggest HTML 4 transitional as a starting point, it shouldn't be too hard to make it validate.

Answer (score 0):

Please move your

> `<style> </style>`

tag into head, should fix the problem, alternatively you can use php to load the style-sheets as a fool-proof method.